# Countup.js final number does not have comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am a javascript noob, no question.

I have JQuery CountUp on my screen and have looked through some of these forums. The counter shows a comma while counting up but the final number (102,050) still shows no comma (102050)

any pointers? here is the code as it sits now...

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  const $this   = $(this) 
  const countTo = $this.attr('data-count')

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({ countNum: countTo },
    {
      duration: 1500,
      easing:'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString('en'));
      },
      complete: function (now) {
        now = Number(Math.ceil(now)).toLocaleString('en');
        $(this).text(now);
        $this.text(this.countNum).toLocaleString('en');
      }
    }
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="102050">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `.toLocaleString('en')` on `this.countNum` not on `$this.text(...)`.
Also you really need only one string of code in the `complete` callback

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  const $this   = $(this) 
  const countTo = $this.attr('data-count')

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({ countNum: countTo },
    {
      duration: 3500,
      easing:'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString('en'));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum.toLocaleString('en'));
      }
    }
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="102050">1</div>
```